# Can I used tableau to connect to the data saved by an application created using google appmaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am creating an application using google app maker. Is it possible for me to access the data saved by the application in the google drive using tableau?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you are saving you data to google sheets.[Info Here](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/5/connect-directly-your-google-sheets-tableau-10-53954)

Comment: I am saving the data in google sheets, is it required for me to export the data to view it in google sheets, or is there a way to access the data in the google sheets without exporting it?